# select two random words from a text with regular expression

Tags: powershell, regex

I have the following code:

```
[string]$namesList = @"

casa fuentes, jose
lopez casimiro juan
gazquez san antonio
anto vazques
"@
```

How do I select the first two words?

```
output expected:

casa fuente
lopez casimiro
gazquez san
anto vazques
```

I have the following code:

```
[string]$names = $namesList.split("`n").ToUpper() | Select-String  "" -AllMatches | ForEach {$_.Matches.value}
```

but I don't know the regular expression to use en select string alguien me ayuda ?¿

Comment: I don't know what is the regex flavour used by PowerShell but if it's PCRE, you can use `^\w+ \w+`. Where `\w+` stands for a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this will do the trick for you:  https://regex101.com/r/6amYCS/1
`(?m)^[\W_]*([^\W_](?:\w|[[:punct:]_-](?=[\w[:punct:]-]))*)[\W_]+([^\W_](?:\w|[[:punct:]_-](?=[\w[:punct:]-]))*)`

The first word is in group 1, the second in group 2.
This is for ASCII, I have one for Unicode if interested as well.